# SQL Server : multiple lines returned for CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select from a single table specific sets of data and then display them grouped under a single field. This however creates a line for each case statement.

I would ideally like to see a single line for each Quote with each of the fields against it.

Would anyone have any ideas how i could improve on what ive done so far?

```
select
   KeyField as Quote,
   CASE WHEN FieldName = 'QTY001' THEN AlphaValue ELSE null END as [QTY],
   CASE WHEN FieldName = 'CON002' THEN AlphaValue ELSE null END as [Conductors],
   CASE WHEN FieldName = 'COP001' THEN AlphaValue ELSE null END as [Copper Size],
   CASE WHEN FieldName = 'COR001' THEN AlphaValue ELSE null END as [Core Length],
   CASE WHEN FieldName = 'COR002' THEN AlphaValue ELSE null END as [Core Inside],
   CASE WHEN FieldName = 'END001' THEN AlphaValue ELSE null END as [End Winding],
   CASE WHEN FieldName = 'KV_001' THEN AlphaValue ELSE null END as [KV],
   CASE WHEN FieldName = 'KW_001' THEN AlphaValue ELSE null END as [KW],
   CASE WHEN FieldName = 'NAM001' THEN AlphaValue ELSE null END as [OEM],
   CASE WHEN FieldName = 'SLO001' THEN AlphaValue ELSE null END as [Slots],
   CASE WHEN FieldName = 'SPE001' THEN AlphaValue ELSE null END as [Speed],
   CASE WHEN FieldName = 'TUR001' THEN AlphaValue ELSE null END as [Turns],
   CASE WHEN FieldName = 'TYP001' THEN AlphaValue ELSE null END as [Type/Description]
from 
   AdmFormData 
where 
   FormType = 'QOT'
```

Comment: could you provide an example for your current and your desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT ...,
      MAX(CASE WHEN FieldName = 'QTY001' THEN AlphaValue ELSE null END) as [QTY],
       .....
FROM...
WHERE...
GROUP BY KeyField
```

Comment: Easy when you know how, knew the Group by, but not the MAX, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to multiple `case when ...` statements, you could use SQLServer's PIVOT facility:

```
select
   KeyField as Quote,
   [QTY001] as [QTY],
   [CON002] as [Conductors],
   [COP001] as [Copper Size],
   [COR001] as [Core Length],
   [COR002] as [Core Inside],
   [END001] as [End Winding],
   [KV_001] as [KV],
   [KW_001] as [KW],
   [NAM001] as [OEM],
   [SLO001] as [Slots],
   [SPE001] as [Speed],
   [TUR001] as [Turns],
   [TYP001] as [Type/Description]
from 
   (select KeyField, FieldName, AlphaValue 
    from AdmFormData
    where FormType ='QOT') as s
pivot
   (max(AlphaValue) for FieldName in 
    ([QTY001], [CON002], [COP001], [COR001], [COR002], [END001], [KV_001], [KW_001], [NAM001], [SLO001], [SPE001], [TUR001], [TYP001])
   ) as p
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have MSSQL 2005 and above you can use [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) command:

```
SELECT KeyField, [QTY001], [CON002], [COR001]
FROM (
    SELECT KeyField, FieldName, AlphaValue FROM data
  ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT (
    MAX(AlphaValue)
    FOR FieldName IN([QTY001], [CON002], [COR001])
  ) AS PivotTable
```

In other case, your solution is the only way to achieve that.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9ef73/8)